# How to subtract from date given as user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

So I'm trying to subtract one day from a users input of 2018-02-22 for example. Im a little bit stuck with line 5 - my friend who is is leaps and bounds ahead of me suggested I try this method for subtracting one day.

In my online lessons I haven't quite got to datetime yet so Im trying to ghetto it together by reading posts online but got a stuck with the error :

TypeError: descriptor 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
date1 = datetime.date()
new = date1.replace(day=date1.day-1, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

print (new)
```

So my aim is the get the out put 2018-02-21 if I put in 2018-02-22.

Any help would be amazing :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all a `timedelta`is best used for the purpose of doing date arithmetcs. You import `timedelta` but don't use it.

```
day = timedelta(days=1)
newdate = input_datetime - day
```

Second problem is you're not initializing a `date` object properly. But in this case it would be better to use datetime as well as `strptime` to parse the datetime from the input string in a certain format.

```
date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
input_date = datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%Y-%m-%d")
day = timedelta(days=1)
newdate = input_datetime - day
```

Comment: Ahh that works much better, thank you so much!! I have found that it is still printing the 24/02/2018 00:00:00 time within that as well. The original user input date works fine just the subtracted date does not. I could splice it out maybe ? 

`date_entry = input('Enter the week ending sunday YYYY-MM-DD format')
sheet['T3'] = date_entry
sheet['E26'] = date_entry
input_date = datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%Y-%m-%d")
day = timedelta(days=1)
newdate = input_date - day
sheet['E25'] = newdate`

Comment: You could just use `newdate.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` to display the `datetime` object in any format you want with or without the time. You could also use `newdate.date()` to get the date part of the `datetime` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
    date1 = datetime.strptime(date_entry, '%Y-%m-%d')
    print date1+timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_entry = input('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format ')

# convert date into datetime object
date1 = datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%Y-%m-%d")  

new_date = date1 -timedelta(days=1)  # subtract 1 day from date

# convert date into original string like format 
new_date = datetime.strftime(new_date, "%Y-%m-%d") 

print(new_date)
```

Output:

```
Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format 2017-01-01

'2016-12-31'
```

Comment: This works wonderfully @AkshayNevrekar

When I start to change the date for multiple subtractions it seem to adding the HHMMSS back into it ? So for the subtract of 1 day it does `20/02/2018` but then for the others it does this 

`19/02/2018 00:00:00`

Comment: multiple subtractions? can you explain furthermore? maybe editing your question.